# Confusion about C macro expansion in enum

Tags: c

I see below code snippet in [fwts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FirmwareTestSuite/Reference?action=show&redirect=Kernel%2FReference%2Ffwts) code base:

```
#define FWTS_CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
#define FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(a,b) FWTS_CONCAT(a, b)
#define FWTS_ASSERT(e, m)   \
enum { FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(FWTS_ASSERT_ ## m ## _in_line_, __LINE__) = 1 / !!(e) }

#define FWTS_REGISTER_FEATURES(name, ops, priority, flags, features)    \
/* Ensure name is not too long */                   \
FWTS_ASSERT(FWTS_ARRAY_LEN(name) < 16,                  \
    fwts_register_name_too_long);
```

My questions are:

- For the definition of `FWTS_ASSERT(e, m)`, I know the `!!` can convert whatever value into 1 or 0. But doesn't it cause error for `FWTS_ASSERT()` when `!!(e)` evaluates to `0` thus leads to `1/0` ?
- And btw, the `FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(a,b)` and `FWTS_CONCAT(a, b)` seem to be duplicated, why do we need 2 of them?

### ADD 1

Based on `@Klas Lindbäck`'s answer, I want to go through the macro expansion with a concrete example.

Suppose I have:

```
#define M_1  abc
#define M_2  123
```

Then I *guess* the expansion process of `FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(M_1,M_2)` should be:

```
FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(M_1,M_2)
->
FWTS_CONCAT(abc, 123)
->
abc123
```

If I directly applying `FWTS_CONCAT(M_1, M_2)`, will it be expanded like this?

```
FWTS_CONCAT(M_1, M_2)
->
M_1M_2
-> 
Bang! M_1M_2 is an invalid symbol!
```

(Please correct me if I am wrong...)

### ADD 2

Tried with `gcc -E macroTest.c -o macroTest.i`:

(macroTest.c)

```
#define M_1  abc
#define M_2  123
#define FWTS_CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
#define FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(a,b) FWTS_CONCAT(a, b)

FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(M_1, M_2)
FWTS_CONCAT(M_1,M_2)
```

(macroTest.i)

```
# 1 "macroTest.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "macroTest.c"

abc123
M_1M_2
```

I think I get the point of the macro expansion rule. Below are some related concepts and quotation:

[Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan):

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded ***before*** they are
>   substituted into a macro body, unless they are ***stringified*** or ***pasted***
>   with other tokens. After substitution, the entire macro body,
>   including the substituted arguments, is scanned ***again*** for macros to be
>   expanded. The result is that the arguments are scanned twice to expand
>   macro calls in them.

[Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

> When a macro parameter is used with a leading ‘#’, the preprocessor
>   replaces it with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to
>   a ***string constant***.

[Token Pasting / Token Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> It is often useful to merge two tokens into one while expanding
>   macros. This is called ***token pasting*** or ***token concatenation***. The ‘##’
>   preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro is
>   expanded, the two tokens on either side of each ‘##’ operator are
>   combined into a single token, which then replaces the ‘##’ and the two
>   original tokens in the macro expansion.

So the detailed process of my scenario is like this:

```
FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(M_1, M_2)   
-> FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(abc, 123) // M_1, M_2 pre-expanded since FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND has no ##.
-> FWTS_CONCAT(abc, 123) // FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND expanded into FWTS_CONCAT
-> abc123  // FWTS_CONCAT expanded

FWTS_CONCAT(M_1,M_2)
-> M_1M_2 //M_1, M_2 are not pre-expanded because of the ## in FWTS_CONCAT
-> DEADEND
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to cause an error.

Comment: It most likely is supposed to cause a compilation error, since the constant `1/0` can't be computed.

Comment: Thanks. But I just don't understand why define a `enum` type to raise compile-time error? Anything special about `enum`?

Comment: @smwikipedia: Other than its values having to be constant (And having a single line error output, giving the identifier's complaint)? I've seen similar done with arrays sizes, but this wouldn't (even accidentally) allocate any storage for the item.

Comment: `enum` is nothing special in this; I have used `typedef` arrays with similar trick. Point is that we perform compile time check with C constructs, when preprocessor won't work. For example, you cannot use `sizeof` in `#if` statement to test array size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macros are used for compile time checking. This is useful when you write code that will be compiled and run on many different platforms and where some platforms may not be compatible.

If the first parameter to `FWTS_ASSERT` evaluates to non-zero (true) then `!!(e)` will evaluate to 1 and the enum will be created with the name `FWTS_ASSERT_<second parameter>_in_line_<line>`. I suspect that the enum is never actually used.

If the first parameter to `FWTS_ASSERT` evaluates to `0` (= false) then the compiler will try to compute `1/0` and generate a compiler error where it will hopefully tell which enum member caused the error, in this case `FWTS_ASSERT_fwts_register_name_to_long_in_line_4`.

> And btw, the FWTS_CONCAT_EXPAND(a,b) and FWTS_CONCAT(a, b) seem to be duplicated, why do we need 2 of them?

`FTW_CONCAT_EXPAND` is done in 2 steps because we want to first expand any macros in the parameters and then perform the concatenation. Doing it in two steps makes the preprocessor do macro expansion of the parameters before it does the string concatenation.

Comment: @smwikipedia A good way to find out would be to try it yourself!  ;-)